# Creating a multi-fonting of a specific word using sphinx-latexpdf generation

Tags: fonts, pdf

I am using sphinx to generate multiple document formats. Since this is a TeX/LaTeX specific forum, and one of the main outputs is .pdf I thought it useful to ask here.

Is it possible to ask latex to output a specific word in a multi-font, and colour appearance every time it occurs in the document. The word should be written this way no matter where it occurs, both in headings, or body text.

More specifically:

- The word is: “AccuROAM” spelt as one word with no spaces as shown,
- "Accu" is in century Gothic font, black in colour RGB(0,0,0), and normal weight,
- "ROAM" is in Calibri font, red in colour RGB(165,0,33), and normal weight,
- Weight should remain constant, even in bold text surroundings.
- Size should be same as the surrounding text

Picture explanation: [image]

Any help is well appreciated,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on [dgoodmaniii's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202903/) but uses XeLaTeX to select system fonts. I don't have Century Gothic so I've substituted `fontconfig`'s choice. I've also used `\newcommand*` rather than `\def` since this is a LaTeX document. The example shows that the weight of the name remains constant. The `fontspec` facility to scale a font to the surrounding text size is used to scale both fonts appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\calibrifam[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Calibri}
\newfontface\cgothicfam[Scale=MatchUppercase]{TeX Gyre Adventor}% I don't have Century Gothic
\newcommand*\accuroam{%
  {\cgothicfam Accu}%
  {\calibrifam\textcolor{myred}{ROAM}}%
}%
\begin{document}
\Huge
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of
\accuroam.

\normalsize\bfseries
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of
\accuroam.

\normalfont\tiny
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of
\accuroam.
\end{document}
```

[image: AccuRoam with XeLaTeX and fontspec]

Comment: @dgoodmaniii Aha. But it is actually XeTeX. At least, that's what I tested with. (Probably LuaTeX would work as well.)

Comment: I took this and used XeLatex to compile it. It works good, needs a little jiging to get the century gothic but shouldnt be too bad. All I need now is to find how to configure sphinx to use Xelatex and auto writethe \accuroam command from the rst file

Comment: @Pearse I think you'd be better off asking a new question specifically about that. I don't have any idea what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

TeX is a macro language, so yes, this is absolutely possible, even easy.  I don't happen to have those particular fonts available to me at the moment, but here's a rough-and-ready example using Computer Modern Sans and Computer Modern Serif, just to show how simple using two separate fonts is.  I've selected those fonts in a generic way to show how you'd select yours, assuming they are installed and ready to use on your system.  If you're using LuaTeX and fontspec, the font selection will be different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\def\accuroam{%
    \usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}Accu%
    \usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}\textcolor{myred}{ROAM}%
}%
\begin{document}
\Huge
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of
\accuroam.

\normalsize
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of
\accuroam.

\tiny
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of
\accuroam.
\end{document}
```

This shows the macro working at three different sizes, and I defined a color `myred` according to your specifications for the red.  Adjustments for the sizes of the capitals and things of that nature can easily be added.

Comment: This is great, i can add the required fonts no problem. I see this adds \accuroam as a command. Since i use sphinx and write the document in rst. Can i make sphinx write "\accuroam" when "accuroam" occurs in the rst file and the latex builder is invoked. This way i avoid changing the output of other document formats created from the same rst file.

Comment: I would imagine there's a way, but I don't know Sphinx.  Their team should be able to help with that.

Comment: I somehow doubt that @dgoodmaniii has Calibri, for example, set up for use with (pdf)TeX. Of course, this could be done if the licence allows it but I think an XeTeX or LuaTeX solution would be preferable here.

Comment: As I noted, that's correct; I don't.  A Xe/LuaTeX solution might well be easier; as I noted, in such a case the font selection would be different.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I doubt that @Pearse has them set up for use with (pdf)TeX. If not, it is not just a question of substituting the correct fonts.

Comment: Hey, I got the sphinx issue sorted. The example above worked well when i added it however I have realised that pdflatex does not like when the \accuroam command is in a section heading. The LaTeX Error: Underdefined colour "myred" seems to stop the build. The font type and weight then changes. What i would like is for the word to appear as detailed above without affecting/being affected by the section heading.

Comment: Try using `\DeclareRobustCommand` rather than `\newcommand`; that should resolve the issue.