# Latex Confused with Word in heading

Tags: fonts

I have set up a document to show a word in a specific way, I Have also used the times package to set the document font as shown

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,oneside]{sphinxmanual}
\usepackage[T1}{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\DeclareRobustCommand\accuroam{%
    \usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}Accu%
    \usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}\textcolor{myred}{ROAM}
}%

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Everything this seems to work until the command `\accuroam` is encountered. It then changes the text following it to cmss normal weight (same as the ROAM in the \accuroam).

How can i fix this so that only the word is changed and not the rest of the text.

Note: I currently use pdflatex as the builder and I am not able to avail of xelatex yet.

Any help well appreciated.

Comment: Note that, unless you can't avoid it, it's my understanding that you can use the saner commands `\textsf` (or the switch `\sffamily`) and `\textrm` (`\rmfamily`) instead of the generalized `\usefont`.

Comment: @SeanAllred There is a switch of font family. However, you *can* use `\fontencoding{}\fontfamily{}...\selectfont` though I'm not sure whether that is saner or not.

Comment: Are you sure about using Computer Modern in a Times environment?

Comment: I am only using times as it is a default output from sphinx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to switch to Computer Modern particularly if the main document font is Times.

The problem is, as has already been said, that `\usefont...` tells TeX to use the chosen font from that point on (respecting grouping).

My suggestion is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\accuroam{%
  \textnormal{Accu\color{myred}\sffamily ROAM}%
}
```

With `\textnormal` you choose the main document font (at the current size); inside it you can change color and font family; at the closing brace, `\sffamily` will end its scope.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\DeclareRobustCommand\accuroam{%
  \textnormal{Accu\color{myred}\sffamily ROAM}%
}

\begin{document}
We describe \accuroam{} which is a very bright idea.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is [supposed to be a logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202894/creating-a-multi-fonting-of-a-specific-word-using-sphinx-latexpdf-generation). However, I'm not at all sure why the OP now wants to use Computer Modern when the original question made the use of Century Gothic and Calibri seem essential. (The code here seems to be from [dgoodmaniii's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202903/) although that's not acknowledged in this question.

Comment: Appologies for not acknowledging @dgoodmaniii code. The reason I dont use the intended font is because I currently cannot use xelatex or luatex to compile it, so I am using a temporary alternative that are available in latex by default until I install the intended fonts.

Answer (score 10):

The font-changing commands are *switch* commands. That is, they apply to all following content until another switch is encountered or the group ends.

Correct the issue by placing each special font inside a group with the text it's meant to style. I also added a trailing `%` to the line containing the red text to prevent spurious spaces in the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % `times' is obsolete

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\DeclareRobustCommand\accuroam{%
    {\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}Accu}%
    {\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}\textcolor{myred}{ROAM}}%
}%

\begin{document}
Test\dots \accuroam{}\dots Test.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also note that the [`times`](http://ctan.org/pkg/times) package is obsolete. Newer alternatives are either the [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) package or `newtxtext`/`newtxmath`.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to switch back to the OT1 encoding since you are using T1 anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% `times' is obsolete
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\DeclareRobustCommand\accuroam{%
    {%
       \fontencoding{T1}%
       \fontfamily{cmr}%
       \fontseries{m}%
       \fontshape{n}%
       \selectfont Accu%
       \fontfamily{cmss}%
       \selectfont\textcolor{myred}{ROAM}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
Test\dots \accuroam{}\dots Test.
\end{document}
```

I've used the longer font specification commands (rather than `\usefont...`) just to make clear what is going on. Note that the second switch only requires a family specification because the first switch already ensures that the encoding, shape and series are correct.

[image: AccuROAM]