# Section headings in classicthesis and mathbf gives wrong capitalization

Tags: sectioning, classicthesis, capitalization

Consider the following TeX (which I compile with XeLaTeX).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[beramono,eulermath]{classicthesis}

\title{On Something}
\author{Someone}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% I'm used to define categories with a boldface
\newcommand{\ABCD}{\mathbf{ABCD}}

\chapter{Theory of $\ABCD$}
\section{Main theorem on $\ABCD$}
It is wel known that ...

\end{document}
```

It compiles and gives the following output:

[image: Weird output in section heading]

As you can see, the 'abcd' in the section heading is lower case. How can I fix this (to be upper case)?

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is set in small caps, there are no bold small caps.

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\ABCD}{\mathbf{ABCD}}`

Comment: @egreg: thanks that did the job! Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is similar to the one in [Latex Confused with Word in heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204040/latex-confused-with-word-in-heading)

You solve it by doing

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ABCD}{\mathbf{ABCD}}
```

so LaTeX won't see `ABCD` and try to lowercase it. However, you should think whether the style you're using is compatible with having math in titles. It isn't, in my opinion.